# Building OpenSSL for Android (ARMv7) on Win32

Tags: android, openssl

How can I build OpenSSL for Android ARM v7 (using Android NDK) on Win32?

Answer (score 1):

Until the OpenSSL's [wiki](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) and setenv-android.sh are updated accordingly, I'll publish the recipe here. The required fixes to the process are:

1. Update setenv-android.sh to support Windows.
2. Update PATH to use Android NDK's (mingw) GNU make (rather than Cygwin's).
3. Invoke `make` with a Windows-style path to Cygwin's perl.

This recipe will be a strange hybrid of Cygwin and mingw (since Android NDK gcc toolchains for win32 are mingw). I'm assuming a Windows x86_64 build of the Android NDK unpacked into **c:\android-ndk-r9d**, and that you wish to use a gcc 4.8 toolchain.

1. Install Android NDK (duh!).
2. Install Cygwin -- make sure to include **perl**
3. Start Cygwin shell as an administrator to make sure native symlinks will work.

Within the console, run the following script to set the variables:

```
export \
  CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native \
  ANDROID_API=android-14 \
  ANDROID_DEV=c:/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr \
  PATH=/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9d/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin:/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin:$PATH \
  MACHINE=armv7 \
  SYSTEM=android \
  ARCH=arm \
  CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi-
```

Now, unpack openssl:

1. `tar xzfv openssl-1.0.1i.tar.gz` (or whatever your tarball is)
2. `cd openssl-1.0.1i` (or whatever your version is)

Make sure you have actual native Win32 (!) symlinks in include/openssl:

```
cmd /c "dir include\openssl"
```

You should see something like:

```
13-Aug-14  05:59 PM    <SYMLINK>      aes.h [..\..\crypto\aes\aes.h]
13-Aug-14  05:59 PM    <SYMLINK>      asn1.h [..\..\crypto\asn1\asn1.h]
```

(etc.)

Now it's time to configure:

```
./config shared -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-comp -no-hw -no-engine --openssldir=/foo/bar
```

Ignore the failure to build (due to failure to find perl). We'll rectify this right away. Do this:

```
make PERL=$(cygpath -w $(which perl))
```

Now wait for a few minutes until it builds, and presto, you have your libcrypto.so etc.

Comment: *"Until the OpenSSL's wiki and setenv-android.sh are updated accordingly..."* - that probably won't happen anytime soon. I don't think I've ever seen a request for OpenSSL/Android/Windows (besides this one). If you create a script `setenv-android-win.sh`, I'd be happy to add it to the Wiki, link back to this question and give you credit.

Comment: @jww - I guessed that won't happen until I do it :)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I've probably taken the hard way. Should've used MSYS.

Comment: if you send me your email, I will create an account for you on the OpenSSL wiki. You can then write an article yourself and upload the necessary files. It will save you time and hassles with coordinating with me :) My email is in my profile.

Comment: @jww Sorry for asking here but what do I do if I have a problem with building on Debianx64 as well? I built openssl using the Wiki page but the result was 64bit rather than 32bit arm file. I am not sure whether I have to download 32bit debian or just set up something in the installation.

Comment: Hello, I tried your method, but I keep failing at the make. It tells me: `make: *** No rule to make target \`/cygdrive/c/openssl/Configurations/unix-Makefile.tmpl', needed by \`configdata.pm'.  Stop.` Of course the requested file is in position.Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of comments on my experience with this:
Executing this statement:

PERL=$(cygpath -w $(which perl))

in the cygwin shell allows the shell to interpret the backslashes as escape characters and the build process chokes.  To solve this I did the following:

$ echo $(cygpath -w $(which perl))

which produced the windows formatted path to the perl executable:

C:\cygwin64\bin\perl

Then I added this line to the export shown above:

PERL=c:/cygwin64/bin/perl \

There are other ways of doing this, but it worked and headed off the problem with the ./config statement documented above (not finding perl).

Second issue was the -no- statements.  After running the configure, the script reports that you'll have to run make depend.  I wanted to exclude MD5 (i.e. -no-md5) and when I did the make depend, it errored out with a report that MD5 was disabled.  Uhhh, yes, that was kind of the idea, but I just won't use MD5 hashes.  I did use the -no-ssl2 and didn't get any complaints after the make depend.

Third issue and this is a mystery.  The build broke on compiling crypto because it could not find a symbol that is supposed to be defined in /crypto/objects/obj_xref.h.  When I looked at the file, it was empty.  Something in the perl script I suppose, but no time to debug right now, since I'm at proof of concept phase.  I placed a copy from a patch that I picked up at https://github.com/devpack/openssl-android

After that, my build ran to completion.  I've done no testing with this and it is not a trustworthy solution, but it did compile and produce the static libraries that I need for proof of concept for my client.

Just as an update, my shared library built with these libraries loaded fine on my target.